# TClientSocket does not connect if I try to connect it in TIdTCPServer::OnConnect event

Tags: c++, indy

I am using Embarcadero C++Builder and I have Indy 10.6.2.0 installed.

I have 4 components on my form:

```
TIdTCPClient *Client;
TIdTCPServer *Server;

TClientSocket *ClientSocket;
TServerSocket *ServerSocket;
```

`Client` is configured to connect to `Server`;
`ClientSocket` is configured to connect to `ServerSocket`;

If I assign `ClientConnect()` to the `Button1::OnClick` event, it connects successfully.

If I assign `ClientSocket->Active=true` to the `Button2::OnClick` event, it also connects successfully.

However, if I try to connect by setting `ClientSocket->Active=true` in

```
Server::OnConnect event:
{
    ClientSocket->Active=true;
}
```

It doesn't work. The same is true if I try to connect in the `OnContextCreate` or `OnExecute` events.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `TClientSocket` operates in **non-blocking mode** (`TClientSocket::ClientType = ctNonBlocking`).  In that mode, the client uses an `HWND` window internally to handle socket events. It also means that the client connects to its server *asynchronously*, delivering a completion event to its `HWND` once the connection is successful or fails.

An `HWND` window has thread affinity, meaning it can only operate within the thread that creates it, and that thread must have a message loop to process and dispatch any messages that are sent to that window.

The `TButton` events are being fired in the main UI thread, and thus use the main UI message loop for processing.  If the `TClientSocket` creates its `HWND` in the main UI thread, then everything is handled for you.

However, the `TIdTCPServer` events are fired in separate worker threads, one for each client that connects to it, and those threads do not have messages loops by default.  So, you can't use `TClientSocket` in *non-blocking* mode inside of a `TIdTCPServer` thread without some extra work. Specifically, you must *either*:

- give each `TIdTCPServer` client thread a message-dispatching loop, ie in the server's `OnExecute` event.
- otherwise, put the `TClientSocket` into **blocking mode** (`TClientSocket::ClientType = ctBlocking`) instead, in which case no `HWND` is used at all, and the client connects to its server *synchronously*.  However, you will then have to use a `TWinSocketStream` object to handle all reads/writes on that `TClientSocket` after its connection is successful.